# Show that all extensions of $\rho$ can be obtained as a channel applied to its purification

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-operation, purification

I am struggling with this exercise here:

Let $H:A, H_E$ and $H_{E′}$ denote complex Euclidean spaces. Consider a purification $|ψ_{AE}⟩⟨ψ_{AE}| ∈ D(H_A ⊗ H_E)$ of a quantum state $ρ_A ∈ D(H_A)$ and
a quantum state $σ_{AE′} ∈ D(H_A ⊗ H_{E′})$ such that $Tr_{E′} [σ_{AE′}] = ρ_A$.

Show that there exists a quantum channel $S : B(H_E) → B(H_{E′})$ such that
$(id_A ⊗ S) (|ψ_{AE}⟩⟨ψ_{AE}|) = σ_{AE′}$.

Attempt:
I know that since pure states are the extreme points of the set of quantum states (which is convex), it suffices to show this for pure states.

To show for $ σ_{AE′}$ being a pure state$(σ_{AE′}=|ψ_{AE'}⟩⟨ψ_{AE'}|)$.
I try using the fact that for different purifications of the same state, we have an isometry V s.t.
$(id_A \otimes V)|ψ_{AE}⟩=|ψ_{AE'}⟩$  but i get stuck at:
$$
σ_{AE′}=(id_A \otimes V)|ψ_{AE'}⟩⟨ψ_{AE'}|(id_A \otimes V^{\dagger})
$$

Answer (score 2):

Changing your notation for clarity, for a fixed state $\rho_A$, we are given $\sigma_{AE'}\in \text{D}(\mathcal{H}_{AE'})$ and $|\psi_{AE}\rangle \in \mathcal{H}_{AE}$ such that
\begin{equation}
\text{Tr}_{E'}(\sigma_{AE'}) = \rho_A = \text{Tr}_{E}|\psi_{AE}\rangle \langle \psi_{AE}| \tag{1}
\end{equation}
You've already found the answer for when $\sigma_{AE'}$ is a pure state $|\phi_{AE'}\rangle \langle \phi_{AE'}|$:  Since purifications are isometrically related, then  implies that there is some isometry $V: \mathcal{H}_E \rightarrow \mathcal{H}_{E'}$ such that
\begin{equation}
|\phi_{AE'}\rangle = (I_A \otimes V)|\psi_{AE}\rangle, \tag{2}
\end{equation}
and the channel you want is just an isometry channel $\mathcal{V}: \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H}_E) \rightarrow \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H}_{E'})$ defined by conjugation $\mathcal{V}(\rho):= V\rho V^\dagger$. Then, from Eq. (2) we have
\begin{equation}
(I_A\otimes \mathcal{V})(|\psi_{AE}\rangle \langle \psi_{AE}|) = \sigma_{AE'}. \tag{3}
\end{equation}

---

More generally, for a mixed state $\sigma_{AE'}$ you can just follow the same procedure but use a purification of $\sigma_{AE'}$: Let $R$ be a system purifying $\sigma_{AE'}$, containing a state $|\phi_{AE'R}\rangle$ satisfying
\begin{equation}
\sigma_{AE'} = \text{Tr}_R |\phi_{AE'R}\rangle \langle \phi_{AE'R} | \tag{4}
\end{equation}
From Eq. (1), we know that $|\phi_{AE'R}\rangle$ is also a purification for $\rho_A$:
\begin{equation}
\text{Tr}_{E'R}|\phi_{AE'R}\rangle \langle \phi_{AE'R} | =  \text{Tr}_{E'}(\sigma_{AE'}) = \rho_A \tag{5}
\end{equation}
Since purifications are isometrically related, there is some $W: \mathcal{H}_E \rightarrow \mathcal{H}_{E'R}$ such that
\begin{equation}
|\phi_{AE'R}\rangle = (I_A \otimes W)|\psi_{AE}\rangle. \tag{6}
\end{equation}
Then, defining $\mathcal{W}: \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H}_E) \rightarrow \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H}_{E'R})$ according to $\mathcal{W}(\rho):= W\rho W^\dagger$, we arrive at
\begin{equation}
(I_A\otimes \mathcal{S})(|\psi_{AE}\rangle \langle \psi_{AE}|) = \sigma_{AE'} \tag{7}
\end{equation}
with $\mathcal{S} = \text{Tr}_R \circ \mathcal{W}$.

Comment: Could you use the fact that the pure state are the extreme points of the set of states, and that this set is convex to then write S as a convex combination of V?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. But something that comes to mind is, if a mixed state satisfies $\text{Tr}_{E'}\sigma_{AE'} =\rho_A$ this does not imply that $\sigma_{AE'}$ is a convex combination of purifications of $\rho_A$.